# Get text file from document directory ipad

Tags: directory, document, ipa

All,In my requirement need to send a mail with attached text file, which is in document directory,Here i can get the path of file which is in document directory,How do i attach the file from my ipad to send.

here is the code which i have tried

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate=self;

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    // Create and show composer
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSLog(@"directry path %@",paths);
    NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs/log-858743.txt"];

    NSLog(@"directry full path %@",fullPath);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
    NSLog(@"Data value %@",data);

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath];
    if (fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"file is there");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"file is not there");
    }

    [picker setSubject:@"Backup"];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/rtf" fileName:@"log.txt"];
    [picker setMessageBody:@"testing." isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];    }
else{
    // Show some error message here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a sample, try this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

//Imposto l'oggetto
[mViewController setSubject:@"Invio Copia Commissione"];

//Preparo l' A: Devo spezzare gli indirizzi E-mail
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[Globals.AEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
[mViewController setToRecipients:toRecipients];


//Preparo il Cc: Devo spezzare gli indirizzi E-mail
if ([Config.EmailAgg length] != 0) {
    NSArray *CcRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[Config.EmailAgg componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
    [mViewController setCcRecipients:CcRecipients];
}

//Setto il corpo dell'E-mail
[mViewController setMessageBody:Globals.TestoEmail isHTML:NO];


//A questo punto visto che ho fatto 30 salvo il testo anche come file allegato dell'E-mail
[Globals.TestoEmail writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CopiaCommissione.txt", Globals.DocumentsPath] atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData *Allegato = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CopiaCommissione.txt", Globals.DocumentsPath]];
[mViewController addAttachmentData:Allegato mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"CopiaCommissione.txt"];


[self presentModalViewController:mViewController animated:YES];
[mViewController release];
```

try to change mimeType in your code like this

```
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"log.txt"];
```

Comment: How to use this am beginner for iphone

Comment: try only to change [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/rtf" fileName:@"log.txt"]; With [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"log.txt"];